# How to apply array function (previous row calculation) with pandas group by

Tags: python, pandas, linear-algebra, stock, quantitative-finance

I have array function which can apply to pandas dataframe that I got from this post
[How to get the number of previous nearest row which is larger than or equal current row in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67379241/how-to-get-the-number-of-previous-nearest-row-which-is-larger-than-or-equal-curr/67389148#67389148)
here is my function that I got from the post

```
def prev_max_dist(df_col):    
    v = df_col.astype(float).values
    s = v.size
    i = np.arange(s)

    v = np.full((s, s), v)
    v = v - v.T
    v[np.triu_indices(s)] = np.nan

    r = i - (s - np.argmax(v[:, ::-1] >= 0, axis=1) - 1)
    r[r < 0] = 0
    return r
```

This function can apply to data from that post
But this function cannot apply with group by pandas
I have data like this

```
Symbol    Day     Close    
  a          1       1
  a          2       2
  a          3       6
  a          4       4
  a          5       5
  a          6       4
  a          7       5
  b          1       1
  b          2       2
  b          3       6
  b          4       4
  b          5       5
  b          6       4
  b          7       5
```

And I want this function can apply to Symbol A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `explode` after `groupby` / `apply`:

**Your dataframe has to be sorted by `['Symbol', 'Day']` values before operations.**

```
df['pnlr'] = df.groupby('Symbol')['Close'].apply(prev_max_dist).explode().values
```

```
>>> df
   Symbol  Day  Close pnlr
0       a    1      1    0
1       a    2      2    0
2       a    3      6    0
3       a    4      4    1
4       a    5      5    2
5       a    6      4    1
6       a    7      5    2
7       b    1      1    0
8       b    2      2    0
9       b    3      6    0
10      b    4      4    1
11      b    5      5    2
12      b    6      4    1
13      b    7      5    2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You help me second time